# TRIGGER BEFORE A COMMIT (INSERT OR UPDATE)

Tags: oracle, web-services, soap, triggers

I have a **trigger** that calls a **webservice** link.
This link read a **View**, and that **view** is composing a XML.

The problema is: 
The trigger is executed when I have a cod_situation = 6 like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_candidato_chama_link 
       AFTER  INSERT  OR UPDATE ON cand_proc_sel 
         FOR EACH ROW DECLARE   
            v_url VARCHAR2(4000);   
            req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;   
            resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;   
            value VARCHAR2(1536);
           --temp   
           v_count         INTEGER;   
           v_alternativas  VARCHAR2(1000);  
           v_error         VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN   
if (:new.cod_situation = 6 )  THEN
            v_url := 'http://.../frameweb/amxv7/amx_new_employee';
            req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(v_url);
            UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
            resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
            LOOP
              UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE(resp, value, TRUE);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(value);
            END LOOP;
            UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
      END IF;

    EXCEPTION   WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
        UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);

        INSERT INTO integratio_log(data, cod_integracao, status, rotina, obs) VALUES(SYSDATE, 7, 'SUCCESS', 'TEST DOM, TRIGGER URL', 'Url : ' || v_url || ' count test: '|| v_count);   WHEN OTHERS THEN
        v_error := To_Char(SQLERRM);

        INSERT INTO integracao_log(data, cod_integracao, status, rotina, obs) VALUES(SYSDATE, 7, 'FAIL', 'TEST DOM, TRIGGER  URL', 'Url : ' || v_url || ' # qtd: '|| v_count || ' # Erro: ' || v_error);

    END;
```

But, the problem is:

the  **clause where** in the View is just the condition **cod_situation = 6**, but when the **trigger** calls the **webservice** where we read the **View**, I do not have **cod_situation = 6** yet.

So, my question is, how can I call the trigger link, but only after the commit is done in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post commit hook is not available. And this is for good reason: At the point where you access the web service the modified data has already been committed. What should the database do if the commit is successful but the post commit fails?

Generally speaking it is not a good idea to access other systems from a trigger: Your session is still not committed hence a rollback is possible. That would means that your web service has been informed about a transaction in the database that might never be written to disk. This may or may not be catastrophic. Additionally you make the functionality of your database dependent on the availability of the web service which is bad practice in itself.

If you absolutely have to do what you are doing you would do yourself a favor by moving the view reading into a stored procedure and call that from the trigger and the web service.